# No errors on console but html doesn't loading

Tags: angularjs, ng-view

I have no idea why this doesn't work. What I'm doing wrong here? I have no errors in console but html from main.html and about.html doesn't load.

When I use controller directly in html it does work well but when I use above code ng-view doesn't get html from main.html and about.html files.

app.js

```
angular
  .module('invoice2', [
    'ngRoute'
  ])
  .config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .when('/about', {
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
        controller: 'InvoiceController'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  });
```

about.js

```
angular.module('finance2', [])
.factory('currencyConverter', function() {
  var currencies = ['USD', 'EUR', 'CNY'];
  var usdToForeignRates = {
    USD: 1,
    EUR: 0.74,
    CNY: 6.09
  };
  var convert = function (amount, inCurr, outCurr) {
    return amount * usdToForeignRates[outCurr] / usdToForeignRates[inCurr];
  };

  return {
    currencies: currencies,
    convert: convert
  };
});

angular.module('invoice2', ['finance2'])
.controller('InvoiceController', ['currencyConverter', function(currencyConverter) {
  this.qty = 1;
  this.cost = 2;
  this.inCurr = 'EUR';
  this.currencies = currencyConverter.currencies;

  this.total = function total(outCurr) {
    return currencyConverter.convert(this.qty * this.cost, this.inCurr, outCurr);
  };
  this.pay = function pay() {
    window.alert("Thanks!");
  };
}]);
```

index.html

```
<body ng-app="invoice2">        
    <div class="container">
        <div ng-view=""></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't define a module more than once

You are doing

```
angular
  .module('invoice2', [
    'ngRoute'
  ])
```

and later

```
angular.module('invoice2', ['finance2'])
```

which overwrites the first one. Instead, have one array of dependencies, and fetch the module later.

```
// define it once
angular.module('invoice2', ['ngRoute', 'finance2'])

// and get that instance later
var app = angular.module('invoice2');
```

Comment: Just realized your answer is same as mine, however, you beat me by quite some time. Deleting my answer.

Comment: What a shame... now I see what I'm doing wrong. Thanks a lot @nikhil and @Patrick!